# Model binding is not working when creating different type inputs dynamically with AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please look at the code at plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TZI0xM
If the input type is fixed (all text or all checkbox...), there's no problem, data binding is working, but if I defined the input type dynamically, the second input binding doesn't work, please help me.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="prop in currentNode.props">
        {{prop.name}}<input ng-model="prop.value" type="{{prop.type}}"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can post the code , how the data binding is working when fixed

Comment: switch to angular version 1.1.5 and it will work

Comment: [fixed]not a clean approach but works. check this -> http://plnkr.co/edit/lvFSQA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the html

```
<li ng-repeat="prop in currentNode.props">
        {{prop.name}}<input ng-model="prop.value" checked="{{prop.value}}" type="{{prop.type}}"></input>
    </li>
```

and the controller code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentNode = {name:'cube',
                        props:[
                          {name:'displayName',value:'New Cube',type:'text'},
                          {name:'visible',value:'checked',type:'checkbox'}
                        ]};
});
```

And here is plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/zy5Lh9

Hope it helps :)